# inline angular-ui-select with image

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, angular-ui-select

I'm trying to create an inline angular-ui-select box with an image displaying near 1 of the options http://plnkr.co/edit/27g6JYtB7tg0w70ROZDb

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">

<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group"  ng-init="choices=[{'toc_text':'Day 1'}, {'toc_text':'Day 2'},{'toc_text':'Day 3', 'show_flag':true}, {'toc_text':'Day 4'}]">
        <ui-select ng-model="choice.selected" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select day">{{$select.choice.toc_text}}<button ng-show="$select.choice.first_responder"  type="button" class="btn ntbtn-rnote btn-xxs btn-notes">R</button>
            </ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="choice in choices">
                <span ng-bind-html="choice.toc_text"></span>
                <span ng-show="choice.show_flag"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xxs btn-notes">R</button></span>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">Button1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button2</button>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonGroup1" class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button3</button>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
            Comments <span class="badge">4</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm new to using ui-select, and I can't figure out:

1. why the button size changes when you click it
2. why the selected choice isn't being selected when you select it (or at least why it's not displaying as chosen in the select box)

I chose to use angular-ui-select because I couldn't figure out how to get bootstrap-select to display an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think ui-select needs to be bound to an object on the controller to get the binding to work properly.

In the controller, add something like

```
$scope.formData = {};
```

And in the markup, bind to `formData.selectedChoice`

```
<div class="form-group"  ng-init="choices=[{'toc_text':'Day 1'}, {'toc_text':'Day 2'},{'toc_text':'Day 3', 'show_flag':true}, {'toc_text':'Day 4'}]">
            <ui-select ng-model="formData.selectedChoice" theme="bootstrap">
                <ui-select-match placeholder="Select day">{{$select.selected.toc_text}}<button ng-show="$select.choice.first_responder"  type="button" class="btn ntbtn-rnote btn-xxs btn-notes">R</button>
                </ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="choice in choices">
                    <span ng-bind-html="choice.toc_text"></span>
                    <span ng-show="choice.show_flag"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xxs btn-notes">R</button></span>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
        </div>
```

[Heres a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sWP0r1reMfSOCKGbcaXV?p=preview)